# Cannot get the program to write and display properly

Tags: java

OK, time to give the noob a hard time. I am writing a program that is supposed to use an algorithm to write all even integers from 1 to 100 to a file, close the file, then display the results. Then id is supposed to append the file with all of the odd integers from 1 to 100, close the file, reopen and display the results. Something like:
1st list - 2, 4, 6, 8, ......., 98, 100 
2nd list - 2, 4, 6, 8, ......., 98, 100, 1 , 3, 5, ...., 97, 99

I get the even(1st) list fine. The 2nd list displays just the odd numbers. Sure it is something simple, usually is. My brain is mush right now and I am not seeing it. Thanks for any help!!

```
package textFileIO;

import java.io.*;


public class TextFileIO {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Create newFile
    File newFile = new File("numbers.dat");
    newFile.createNewFile();



    int evenNum = 0;
    int oddNum = 0;

   try{
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile)); 


    //Loop from 1 to 100
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i+=2)
    { 
       evenNum += i + 1;
       writer.write("" + i + ", ");
    }   

    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());

    reader.close();

    BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, true)); 

    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i +=2) {  
            oddNum += i;  
            writer2.write("" + i + ", ");  
        }  
    writer2.newLine();
    writer2.close();

    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));

    System.out.printf(reader2.readLine());

   }

   catch (Exception e){

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declaration of `writer2` to

```
BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, true));
```

The `true` will make the writer append to an existing file, rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Because you're only reading one line from the file, the second time through.  You've got even numbers on the first line and odd numbers on the second line.  You could have worked this out if you had just bothered to look at the file.